# Implementation of Java's memory model?

Tags: java, memory-management, shared-memory, parallel-processing

There is a [specification of Java memory model](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=133).

And I want to dive into the source code to actually investigate how those mechanisms are implemented. (e.g., synchronized, volatile, ..., etc.)

But the codebase is so huge, I have no idea where to start with.
(http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/CatalogJava-Document.htm)

Could anyone give me some clues?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: I would suggest looking at [JamVM](http://jamvm.sourceforge.net/). It's significantly smaller than OpenJDK.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might start by looking at the synchronizer.cpp class in the current version of the JDK. Prepare yourself a strong pot of coffee-- you've picked one of the most complex areas of the JVM to start delving into the source code.

If you haven't already done so, I would also suggest that you take a look at [Bill Pugh's page on the Java Memory Model](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/) and Doug Lea's [recommendations for compiler writers on implementing the Java memory model](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jmm/cookbook.html).

You may also glean something from running the debug JVM with the option turned on to output the JIT-compiled assembly which you can then inspect. (This won't tell you everything, but it might give you some pointers in: I think some of the things it prints will if nothing else give you some things to search for in the JDK source code...)